# How do I get an inputstream or a byte array from a class

Tags: java, class, byte, inputstream

```
Class<?> c = (Class<?>) entry.getValue();
                String className = c.getName();
                String p = className.replace('.', '/') ;
                String clazz = p.substring(p.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                InputStream s = c.getResourceAsStream(clazz);
```

So the inputstream is alway null, I tryed a lot of things but it did not work

Comment: Would you so kind as to display for us the values of c and clazz?

Comment: What is datatype of `entry`?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. Are you trying to get the bytes of the instantiated class? The bytes of the class that was loaded with the classloader? What is `entry` is this context?

Comment: ok heres more code : https://gist.github.com/MalikDz/f120b45563f9cb360b61

Comment: Not working , can someone add my skype : malikfootdz

Answer (score 4):

If you want to access the file, you must add the ".class":

```
String clazz = p.substring(p.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + ".class";
```

BTW, you don't need to replace '.'s with '/'es here.

UPDATE: (it the class being read is not in the same package as the class used to load it)

```
String clazz = "/" + p + ".class";
```

Comment: No: he is already removing the package name and that's correct: when you're using Class.getResourceAsStream, the resource name is understood as relative to the class's package.

Comment: @ThomasStets getting the resource Foo.class from the class Foo will search for a file Foo.class in the same package as Foo, which is what the above code is doing.

Comment: Not working , the class is not from an internal  package

Comment: In that case, keep the package (with the '/'s) and add another '/' add the beginning (see update).

Comment: aint working :S :S , if someone could add my skype : malikfootdz

Comment: @MalikDz This is StackOverflow, not Skype. The conversation must continue and be completed *here*. Otherwise the question has zero permanent value and is liable for deletion.